# Lambda Behaviour

Tags: ruby, lambda

I am having difficulty understanding what makes the following behaviour possible (taken from the ruby pickaxe book):

```
def power_proc_generator
  value = 1
  lambda {value += value}
end

power_proc = power_proc_generator

3.times {puts power_proc.call} # => 2,4,8
3.times {puts power_proc_generator.call()} # => 2,2,2
```

I don't see how the "power_proc" object allows the value to continue doubling as I would assume (wrongly it seems) that each call would reassign value to 1.

My question being why does "3.times {puts power_proc.call}" result "2,4,8" and not "2,2,2" ?

Comment: Try to state your question as a question, so there is less confusion.

Comment: Sorry about that I clarified with an actual question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`power_proc_generator` returns a lambda which uses (and modifies) the value of a variable in the surrounding scope. This is known as a closure -- the returned function "closes" over the value of the `value` variable. So each time you call the returned function, it multiplies `value` by two. The important part is that `value` stays around between calls to `power_proc.call`, so you're modifying the existing variable.

Also, to elaborate on the difference between printing `power_proc_generator` and `power_proc.call` -- `power_proc_generator` returns a new function each time it's called, which is why you never see `value` being increased. `power_proc.call`, on the other hand, continues calling the same function multiple times.

Comment: Okay, so I think my problem was less about understanding lambdas and more about not really understanding closures, so closures carry the most recent variable state, the non-object function call would just re-evaluate from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

power_proc_generator returns a lambda that includes 
a closure that contains the variable 'value'.  So that variable hangs
around from one power_proc.call to the next.